# Error al implementar PackageInstallerActivity para algunas versiones de 6.0 de Android

Tags: java, android

Tengo el siguiente codigo que se ejecuta cuando el usuario acepta la actualización de la aplicación dentro de la misma.

Ya proporciono codigo para la compatibilidad con versiones 6.0 + y versiones 6.0 -, el problema surge que algunos dispositivos aceptan la ejecución de codigo que muestro debajo, y algunos otros no., por lo general los dispositivos con versiones 6.0 - no causan problemas realizan la ejecución correctamente, el problema esta en las versiones 6.0 + que algunas realiza las ejecuciones y en algunas otras no. 
 -

```
File fileToUpdate = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator + "nameAppV" + (currentVersionCode + 1) + ".apk");
                    ComponentName comp;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(fileToUpdate), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
                    {
                        comp = new ComponentName("com.android.packageinstaller", "com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerActivity");
                    }
                    else{
                        comp = new ComponentName("com.google.android.packageinstaller", "com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerActivity");
                    }
                    intent.setComponent(comp);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Este es el error que me arroja al intentar la ejecución.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Resumen:**

1.- Tengo implementado el codigo para realizar una instalación de la aplicación cuando haya actualizaciones nuevas.

2.- Se proporciona soporte para versiones 6.0 + y versiones anteriores.

3.- Versiones (SO) anteriores se ejecuta sin problemas.

4.- Versiones 6.0 + se ejecuta en algunos de manera correcta.

5.- En algunas versiones de 6.0 + no se ejecuta el codigo y me arroja el error.

**¡¡SOLUCIONADO!!!**

Al parecer el algunas versiones de android **6.0** aun traen el paquete (*com.android.packageinstaller*) instalado, que posteriormente envian una actualización para solucionar este problema debido a que otros con el mismo telefono,sistema, aplicaciones ya tienen instalado el paquete (*com.google.android.packageinstaller*) actualizado.

Para comprobar el paquete que traen instalado tuve que adquirir un telefono de los que estaban causando problemas con la ejecución de codigo, ejecute el siguiente comando en la consola para verificar el paquete.

Télefono, sistema, aplicaciones,etc. exactamente lo mismo, pero diferente paquete.

```
INPUT -> adb -s ZY22342FG3 exec-out pm list packages -f install
package:/system/app/CertInstaller/CertInstaller.apk=com.android.certinstaller
package:/system/priv-app/GooglePackageInstaller/GooglePackageInstaller.apk=com.android.packageinstaller


INPUT -> adb -s ZY2233Z2S2 exec-out pm list packages -f install
package:/system/app/CertInstaller/CertInstaller.apk=com.android.certinstaller
package:/system/priv-app/GooglePackageInstaller/GooglePackageInstaller.apk=com.google.android.packageinstaller
```

Metodo para verificar si existe el paquete en el dispositivo móvil

```
public boolean isPackageExisted(String targetPackage){
        List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
        PackageManager pm;

        pm = getPackageManager();
        packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
        for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages)
        {
            if(packageInfo.packageName.equals(targetPackage))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Codigo final:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

            File fileToUpdate = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator + "lecturasV" + (currentVersionCode + 1) + ".apk");
            ComponentName comp;
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            //Soporte para 5.1 -
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1 || isPackageExisted("com.android.packageinstaller"))
            {
                Log.e("VERSION: ", "OPT 1 "+ Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(fileToUpdate), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                comp = new ComponentName("com.android.packageinstaller", "com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerActivity");
            }
            //Soporte para 6.0+
            else
            {
                //Soporte para 7.0 +
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                {
                    Uri uriToUpdate = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", fileToUpdate);
                    intent.setDataAndType(uriToUpdate, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                }else{
                //Soporte para 7.0 -
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(fileToUpdate), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                }
                Log.e("VERSION: ", "OPT 2 "+ Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
                comp = new ComponentName("com.google.android.packageinstaller", "com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerActivity");
            }
            intent.setComponent(comp);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas los Flags que defines para requerir permisos, si es mayor o igual a 6.0 debes requerirlos manualmente:

Uno de los permisos que se requieren para [Android 6.0](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) es el de [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) (que implicitamente es tambien `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` :

puedes requerir el permiso antes de tratar de leer el almacenamiento externo, llama este método:

```
private void checkExternalStoragePermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para leer!");
    }
}
```

Puedes validar llamar el metodo unicamente el sistemas operativos mayores o igual a Android 6.0 :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
    //Verifica permisos para Android 6.0+
     checkExternalStoragePermission();
}
```

Android 6 el packageName cambio a `com.android.packageinstaller`, por lo tanto sería de esta forma, cuando es menor a 23 (Android M) usa el anterior método :

```
File fileToUpdate = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator + "nameAppV" + (currentVersionCode + 1) + ".apk");

    ComponentName comp;
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(fileToUpdate), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");  

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1/*23*/){
     comp = new ComponentName("com.android.packageinstaller", "com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerActivity");
    }else{
     comp = new ComponentName("com.google.android.packageinstaller", "com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerActivity");
    }

    intent.setComponent(comp);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Lo de los permisos ya lo tengo implementado, de hecho tengo una clase donde manejo lo de los permisos, y los permisos los uso cuando vaya a necesitar realizar una acción que requiera permisos y almaceno esos permisos en las preferencias de la aplicación para ya no volver a solicitarlos nuevamente, el problema no viene siendo los permisos, si no que no me reconoce la accion que intento realizar en el intent. Como mencione algunas versiones 6.0 no me reconoce la acción, y claro antes de todo esto corroborado que se hayan solicitado los permisos.

Comment: Pero voy a intentar con el nuevo flag que me comentas.

Comment: por lo que me comentas, el único problema es en el paquete, asegura que si es API 22 o menor use "com.android.packageinstaller" si es mayor o igual a 23 use "com.google.android.packageinstaller"

Comment: acabo de realizar algunas modificaciones para proporcionar soporte en android 7.0 +, a partir del  7.0 obligatoriamente requiere un File Provider y en esta versión es necesario tener los flags de los permisos aun si la aplicación ya tenga los permisos de lo contrario la acción es denegada.